# Make a curvy line with css or javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to pull off the curvy line attached below without using images and only using css and/or javascript? Sorry it's tiny and light gray..

It hurts my soul to attach an image for this little guy! Thanks for reading.

[image]

Comment: the image failed to load

Comment: http://is.gd/yourAnswer

Comment: javascript must be no visually, it just makes functions more dynamic browser (visual cases).

Comment: @nnnnnn was what I said, javascript dynamic makes things then the issue would be with him "canvas" specifically and not javascript.

Comment: I think use base64 url is the most resonable and convenient.

Answer (score 2):

### CSS Only

You can use CSS3 [`repeating-linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient)

```css
    .wavy {
        background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent, transparent 9px, #CCC 2px, #CCC 12px),
           repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 9px, #CCC 2px, #CCC 12px);
        height: 8px;
        width: 98px;
    }
```

```html
<p class="wavy"></p>
```

*The above code does not include vendor prefixes since [all major browsers seem to accept it](http://caniuse.com/css-repeating-gradients)*

---

### Static Javascript

```js
   function appendWaves(el){
        var littleGuy = document.createElement('div');
        littleGuy.id="littleGuy";
        littleGuy.setAttribute('style', 'color:#CCC; font-size: 0.8em;');
        littleGuy.innerHTML = '\\/\\/\\/\\/\\/\\/\\';
        el.appendChild(littleGuy);
    }
    
    //example usage
    window.onload = function(){appendWaves(document.body)};
```

---

### Animated CSS

```css
   .wavy {
        -webkit-animation: 0.5s infinite bgPos linear;
        animation: 0.5s infinite bgPos linear;
        background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent, transparent 9px, #ccc 2px, #ccc 12px) repeat scroll 0 0%, repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 9px, #ccc 2px, #ccc 12px) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        height: 8px;
        width: 98px;
        background-size: 114px;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes bgPos {
        0% {
            background-position: 0, 0;
        }
    
        100% {
            background-position: 100% 0, 100% 0;
        };
    }
    
    @keyframes bgPos {
        0% {
            background-position: 0;
        }
    
        100% {
            background-position: 100% 0;
        };
    }
```

```html
<p class="wavy"></p>
```

---

### Animated Javascript

```js
    var waves = '\\/\\/\\/\\/\\/\\/\\';
    function wavy(){
        waves = waves.replace(/\\/g, "•");
        waves = waves.replace(/\//g, "∆");
        waves = waves.replace(/•/g, "/");
        waves = waves.replace(/∆/g, "\\");
        document.getElementById('littleGuy').innerHTML = waves;
        setTimeout(function(){requestAnimationFrame(wavy)}, 150);
    }
    
    function appendWaves(el){
        var littleGuy = document.createElement('div');
        littleGuy.id="littleGuy";
        littleGuy.setAttribute('style', 'color:#CCC; font-size: 0.8em;');
        el.appendChild(littleGuy);
        requestAnimationFrame(wavy);
    }
    window.onload = function(){appendWaves(document.body)};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using alternating `\` and `/` characters in a font that causes them to appear the way you want. Using Times New Roman, the string `\/\/\/\/\/` appears like the zig-zagging curve in your image.
It should work in pretty much **any** browser, including ones with JavaScript disabled, outdated ones without SVG support, or even command line ones like Lynx (which can't even show images).

If this isn't exactly what you want, you can always draw on an HTML5 canvas using JavaScript, or use an SVG (as @sawa pointed out).

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like this:

```
    <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function drawShape(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');

  if (canvas.getContext){

    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0,10);
    ctx.lineTo(10,0);
    ctx.moveTo(10,0);
    ctx.lineTo(20,10);
    ctx.moveTo(20,10);
    ctx.lineTo(30,0);
    ctx.moveTo(30,0);
    ctx.lineTo(40,10);
    ctx.moveTo(40,10);
    ctx.lineTo(50,0);
    ctx.moveTo(50,0);
    ctx.lineTo(60,10);

    ctx.stroke();

  } 
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="drawShape();">
   <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MCZG7/

Answer (score 0):

This **simply works**, have a try!

use base64 url:

```
div {
    background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAANAAAAA8BAMAAADlDCm+AAAAElBMVEX////Jycna2trv7+/k5OTl5eVsfzX+AAAAUElEQVRYw+3HsQnAMAxE0RMkvXbwBp7AI2T/aWIC6a68QIr/jo+QAAAAgG+0VC6lDWm6lFZSu5R2rGfX3r7nen/Fddny5rDlVdsAAAAA/MoNzbkI9oz70dAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=');
}
```

1. You can compress your png here: https://tinypng.com/
2. Transfer it to base64 code: http://www.base64-image.de/

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need CSS or JavaScript. Write a SVG object in the HTML code. If you want to use CSS, you can move the SVG design to CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 options:

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/YBPeL/1/

**Note**: Tested only in Chrome running on a Mac. Test well across your entire target browser set before use. Change fonts in the second option if you need to.

**Option #1**

```
<span class="curvy"></span><span class="curvy"></span><span class="curvy"></span><span class="curvy"></span><span class="curvy"></span><span class="curvy"></span><span class="curvy"></span> 

span.curvy {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    border-left: 1px solid #888;
    border-top: 1px solid #888;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    padding: 0;
    margin-right: 1px;
}
```

**Option #2**

```
<span class="curvy2">^^^^^^^</span>

span.curvy2 {
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #888;
    -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.6,1);
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Segoe UI', Helvetica;
}
```